# What creature has the sharpest fangs?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, lore

I was working on an analogy in a sales pitch to a blacksmith.

"I can make your longsword sharper than the fang of a ...."

My immediate reaction was to fill in the blank with a dragon. I ended up choosing the Fang/Gray Dragon.

Is there any creature in the MM that is considered to have the sharpest teeth in the DnD Universe?

Comment: Hi @MasonT, welcome to StackExchange! This site is a bit different than your usual forum-- we're really building an archive of questions that can have documented, provable answers, which future visitors can access. Your question as currently written might be only answerable with opinions, which would make it better suited for a forum. If your question gets closed, don't take it personally- it's not a judgement on your question, it's just because we try to avoid debates in favor of concrete facts. Check out the [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) center for suggestions

Comment: Say a creature has the highest damaging bite attack, I assume that's *not* what you're looking for and instead you want information and lore on creatures that points towards which ones have the sharpest teeth? Are you interested only in lore and monsters from fifth edition or are previous editions alright as well? I'm also unsure whether the term "sharpness" makes this opinion-based since it isn't exactly something one can measure but at the same time I'm not sure what else could replace the term so it might be alright

Comment: @Medix2 I'll accept lore from any of the previous versions. I think highest damaging bite attack is more a measure of strength than anything, but I'm interested in that knowledge as well.

Comment: @TheGrumbleputty Appreciate the info. I'm looking for Monster Manual lore over opinion based, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Since the question is about a blacksmith's pitch, would the monster need to be widely well known by the population of whatever setting? I ask because the answer could yield an obscure, possibly unique creature that an average blacksmith may not be aware of.

Comment: @DavidCoffron No worries on obscurity, it would just give me the opportunity to strengthen the sales pitch. "Oh you've never heard of "____"... It's said to only come out of hibernation every 100 years hoping that the world has created something strong enough that its teeth cannot pierce!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## There probably is no in-universe answer

Your question is asked from the perspective of a blacksmith in (a non-specific) world of D&D.  It's easy to forget from our lofty perspective of meta-knowledge, but for the characters in the game, this information is basically impossible to know.

Remember that the creatures our exceptional adventurers might encounter range from the strongest demon lords, to unfathomable monsters from the Far Realms, to slumbering behemoths like the tarrasque.  No individual will ever encounter all of these monsters in their lifetime.  Moreover, the odds of anyone taking a [sharpness tester](https://www.catra.org/testing-equipment/razors/sharpness-tester-3/) along to figure out how an astral dreadnought's teeth compare to those of an aboleth seem... slim.

So honestly, anyone in-universe claiming they know what creature has the sharpest teeth is basically guaranteed to be exaggerating.  At that point, they could probably pick anything sufficiently rare and known for having sharp teeth and *claim* that it's superlative.  Nobody would really be able to prove them wrong.

## There doesn't seem to be a meta answer, either

It's difficult to prove that there *isn't* an answer for 5th edition, but various searches on D&D Beyond yield no real results on the "sharpest" fangs.  However, there are various adjectives that the descriptions apply to monster teeth.  Perhaps these will suite your needs.

#### Sharp/Pointed fangs/teeth

Really too many of these to mention, from goblinoids to dinosaurs to fiends.  This probably isn't what you want.

#### Razor-sharp teeth

The [ghoul](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ghoul) is described as having razor-sharp teeth.

Applied to the [aeorian nullifier](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/aeorian-nullifier) from Wildemount, and boy does it have a lot of them.

In at least one adventure, the [death slaad](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/death-slaad) is referred to with the same descriptor.

#### As hard as steel

The [leucrotta](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/leucrotta) has "bony ridges" that are described as "hard as steel," while still being sharp enough to "lacerate flesh".

#### Intentionally sharpened

Some intelligent creatures choose to sharpen their teeth.  Whether this makes them sharper than those creatures with naturally sharp fangs is anyone's guess.  These include hags, as well as various individual NPCs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You make a very good point on how an adventurer would even learn the true sharpness of a monsters teeth. As far as an in-universe answer, it would all be exaggeration or hyperbole. I'll keep digging around the monster manual for the perfect sales pitch!